# Short diagonal arrows inside commutative diagram

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I need to use the `xy` maths package (because I need to make it into a PNG file for Wordpress and mathurl.com accepts the `xy` template) to make a commutative diagram in which there are diagonal 4 shorter arrows inside the diagram, directed inward. The best I can do is

```
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\xymatrix{Y' \ar[r]^{g'}
\ar[d]_{f'} & X' \ar[d]^{f} \\
Y \ar[r]_{g} & X 
\\
%
\ar@{=>}"1,2"*++++\frm{};"2,1"*++\frm{}}
```

So I can only get one arrow, which needs to be higher up to the right.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You can mark code by selecting it and clicking the button marked `{}` above the text field (or hitting Ctrl + K).

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand the question; is something like this what you need? `\xymatrix{Y' \ar[r]^{g'}
\ar[d]_{f'} & X' \ar[d]^{f} \Y \ar[r]_{g} & X \\ar@{=>}"1,2"*++\frm{};"2,1"*++\frm{}
\ar@{=>}"1,1"*++\frm{};"2,2"*++\frm{}}`

Comment: Almost, except the arrows should be shorter with tips at the centre (so those are coming down from the top two corners, and there should also be 2 more arrows coming up from below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use additional rows and columns:

```
\xymatrix@R.8pc@C.8pc{
Y' \ar[rr]^{g'} \ar[dd]_{f'} && X' \ar[dd]^{f} \\
 & \mbox{\phantom{$x$}} \ar@{<=}[ul] \ar@{<=}[ur] \ar@{<=}[dl] \ar@{<=}[dr]   & \\
Y \ar[rr]_{g} && X
}
```

[image]